PDF js text select implementation in VUE js
I am currently facing difficulties with the implementation of text selection in pdf js.
This code is a Vue.js component that displays a PDF document on a canvas element. It uses the pdf.js library to render the PDF and provides functionality to highlight specific areas within the PDF based on coordinates data. It also includes features like tooltips for highlighted areas and handling mouse events for selecting highlighted areas. Additionally, it observes changes in the data store to update the highlighted areas when necessary.
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="pdfCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watchEffect } from "vue";
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import { usePdfOnlyStore } from "@/store/pdf-only/store";

const pdfOnlyStore = usePdfOnlyStore();

const coordinatesData = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(pdfOnlyStore.coordinatesData)
);

let tooltipDiv = null;

const props = defineProps({
  pdfUrl: { type: String, required: true },
});

const pdfCanvas = ref(null);
// let currentHighlightedArea = null;
function removeAllHighlights() {
  if (props.pdfUrl) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const pdfCanvasElement = pdfCanvas.value;
      const offscreenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      offscreenCanvas.width = pdfCanvasElement?.width;
      offscreenCanvas.height = pdfCanvasElement?.height;
      const offscreenContext = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d");

      // Re-render the PDF without highlights to the offscreen canvas
      pdfjsLib.getDocument(props.pdfUrl).promise.then((pdf) => {
        pdf.getPage(1).then((page) => {
          // Get the viewport without explicitly setting the rotation
          const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.4 });
          offscreenCanvas.width = viewport.width;
          offscreenCanvas.height = viewport.height;
          const renderContext = { canvasContext: offscreenContext, viewport };
          page.render(renderContext).promise.then(() => {
            // Swap the offscreen canvas with the visible canvas
            const canvasContext = pdfCanvasElement?.getContext("2d");
            canvasContext?.clearRect(
              0,
              0,
              pdfCanvasElement?.width,
              pdfCanvasElement?.height
            );
            canvasContext?.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0);
            resolve(); // Resolve the promise when done
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

const renderPdf = () => {
  const pdfUrl = props.pdfUrl ? props.pdfUrl : "";
  const pdfCanvasElement = pdfCanvas.value;
  // console.log(coordinatesData)
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
    "https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.7.570/build/pdf.worker.min.js";

  pdfjsLib
    .getDocument(pdfUrl)
    .promise.then((pdf) => pdf.getPage(1))
    .then((page) => {
      const canvasContext = pdfCanvasElement.getContext("2d");
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.4 });
      pdfCanvasElement.height = viewport.height;
      pdfCanvasElement.width = viewport.width;
      const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
      return page.render(renderContext).promise;
    })
    .then(() => {
      const canvasContext = pdfCanvasElement.getContext("2d");
      highlightArea(canvasContext, coordinatesData.total);
      highlightArea(canvasContext, coordinatesData?.invoice_number);
      highlightArea(canvasContext, coordinatesData.currency);
      pdfCanvasElement.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      pdfCanvas.value.addEventListener("click", handleMouseMove);
    });
};

onMounted(() => {
  renderPdf();
});

function highlightArea(ctx, area) {
  const padding = 5;
  ctx.fillStyle = area?.color;
  ctx.fillRect(
    area?.bbox[0] - padding,
    area?.bbox[1] - padding,
    area?.bbox[2] - area?.bbox[0] + 2 * padding,
    area?.bbox[3] - area?.bbox[1] + 2 * padding
  );
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  const canvasRect = pdfCanvas.value.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - canvasRect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - canvasRect.top;

  if (tooltipDiv) tooltipDiv.remove();

  const highlightedArea = getHighlightedArea(x, y);
  if (highlightedArea) {
    tooltipDiv = createTooltip(
      event.clientX,
      event.clientY - 30,
      highlightedArea
    );
    document.body.appendChild(tooltipDiv);
    // Change cursor to pointer when hovering over a highlighted area
    pdfCanvas.value.style.cursor = "pointer";
  } else {
    // Reset cursor to auto when not hovering over a highlighted area
    pdfCanvas.value.style.cursor = "auto";
  }

  // Check if the event is a click event
  if (event.type === "click") {
    // alert(`${highlightedArea} has been selected.`);
    pdfOnlyStore.selectedHighlight = highlightedArea;
  }
}

function getHighlightedArea(x, y) {
  for (const [area, { bbox }] of Object.entries(coordinatesData)) {
    if (x >= bbox[0] && x <= bbox[2] && y >= bbox[1] && y <= bbox[3]) {
      return area;
    }
  }
  return "";
}

async function highlightTotal(item) {
  const canvasContext = pdfCanvas.value?.getContext("2d");
  const bbox = coordinatesData[item].bbox;
  const padding = 3;

  // Wait for all highlights to be removed
  await removeAllHighlights();

  // Re-apply all highlights
  for (const area of Object.values(coordinatesData)) {
    highlightArea(canvasContext, area);
  }

  // Apply the new border
  canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black"; // Set border color to black
  canvasContext.setLineDash([2, 2]); // Set border to dotted
  canvasContext.lineWidth = 1;
  canvasContext.strokeRect(
    bbox[0] - padding,
    bbox[1] - padding,
    bbox[2] - bbox[0] + 2 * padding,
    bbox[3] - bbox[1] + 2 * padding
  );

  //  currentHighlightedArea = item;
}

function createTooltip(left, top, text) {
  const tooltip = document.createElement("div");
  tooltip.textContent = text;
  tooltip.style.cssText = `position: absolute; left: ${left}px; top: ${top}px; background: #f1f1f1; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; z-index: 9999;`;
  return tooltip;
}

watchEffect(() => {
  if (pdfOnlyStore.highlightedFelid) {
    highlightTotal(pdfOnlyStore.highlightedFelid);
  }
});

watchEffect(() => {
  if (pdfOnlyStore.nextPdf) {
    // removeAllHighlights();
    pdfOnlyStore.nextPdf = false;
  }
});

</script>


You should really clarify what are the difficulties you're facing

@JamesZ I need pdf text select feature using pdf js with my current implementation
